# Can you determine where the update occurred inside a $watch callback?

Tags: angularjs

If you have a variable with double binding (`=`) which you are $watching, is it possible to know from where the update was triggered? Like directive name or controller name?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not think so. However, looking for the source of change is likely to lead to tightly coupled and hard to maintain code. Why is access to the source of the change needed?

Comment: Inside a directive, I am trying to determine if the directive code updated the value of a scope property or if it was updated by the parent controller.

Comment: I do not think that should matter (unless you are trying to debug a problem). If the code has two separate code paths for the cases when it is updated from different sources, then you should have two different methods which update the variable instead of having a `$watch`.

Comment: please post your code etc on a JSFiddle. Or describe exact problem. You probably don't need to know where it was updated at.

Comment: I rewrote it so I don't need it, but it would still be interesting to know if you can determine if the update was internal or external.